# Sort array based on duplicate values

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array which contains duplicate values. I want to sort the array so that the values with the most duplicates appear first in line.

I want an output like:

```
Rihanna
U2
Becca
Taylor Swift
```

My file that contains data:

```
rihanna
rihanna
rihanna
rihanna
taylor swift
becca
becca
u2
u2
u2
```

My code as is which wont work:

```
$input = file_get_contents('files');
$input = explode("\n", $input);

$acv = array_count_values($input);
$acv = arsort($acv); 
$result = array_keys($acv);
print_r($acv); //Outputs Blank
```

Comment: You can use php function array_unique for this.

Comment: I tried the following code before: `print_r(array_unique($input));` but doesnt sort by order i want. Returns: `Array ( [0] => rihanna [4] => taylor swift [5] => becca [7] => u2 [10] => ) `

Comment: On what basis do you want the sorting to be done? You should do the sorting after the sanitizing the duplicates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your solution
your array is :

```
$arr = array('rihanna','rihanna','rihanna','rihanna','taylor swift','becca','becca','u2','u2','u2');

$acv = array_count_values($input);
// If need to remove element with count = 1

foreach($acv as $key => $value)
{
    echo $value;
    if($value == 1)
    {
        unset($nArr[$key]);
    }
}
//End
$fArr = array_flip($acv);

krsort($fArr);
print_r(array_values($fArr));

//output
Array
(
    [0] => rihanna
    [1] => u2
    [2] => becca
    [3] => taylor swift
)
```

Comment: That works a charm! Thank you very much. For educational purposes.. How would one go about making it display AS IS above, but without `taylor swift`? So display in order by highest dupe but dont display a result if there is only one record of it?